# Change GridViewColumn text color base on condition

Tags: wpf, listview, datagridviewcolumn

This is my `GridViewColumn`:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="180" Header="Status">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Txt" Text="{Binding Status}" Foreground="Yellow" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

The Status `field` is a property of my binding object and all i want to do is change this `GridViewColumn` color but this time base on condition:

I have another propgerty called `StatusMessage` which is simple `enum`:

```
public enum StatusMessage
{
    InProcess,
    Done,
    Wait
}
```

So this `enum` property is changing all the time and for every value of this `enum` i want to define different color.
Is it possible ?

**Edit**

My View model class inherit from `BaseObservableObject`:

```
public class BaseObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> raiser)
    {
        var propName = ((MemberExpression)raiser.Body).Member.Name;
        OnPropertyChanged(propName);
    }

    protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
        {
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(name);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

My properties:

```
public string Status
{
    get { return _status; }
    set
    {
        _status = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public StatusMsg StatusMessage
{
    get { return _statusMsg; }
    set {
        _statusMsg = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="180" Header="Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status}">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding StatusMsg,Converter={c:StatusMessageToColorConverter}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

`StatusMessageToColorConverter` is the same as @grek40 suggested and still my `TextBlock` `Foreground` not changing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I first focus on the value conversion, then I say something about the other requirement ("So this enum property is changing all the time and for every value of this enum i want to define different color.")

Since you have an enum value but you want to have a color specification, you need to *convert* the value. This can be done with the help of an implementation of the `IConverter` interface. There are different ways to reference a converter in XAML, I additionally inherit from `MarkupExtension` so I am able to access the converter directly.

```
public class StatusMessageToColorConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    // one way converter from enum StatusMessage to color
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is StatusMessage && targetType == typeof(Brush))
        {
            switch ((StatusMessage)value)
            {
                case StatusMessage.InProcess:
                    return Brushes.Yellow;
                case StatusMessage.Done:
                    return Brushes.Green;
                case StatusMessage.Wait:
                    return Brushes.Red;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public StatusMessageToColorConverter()
    {
    }

    // MarkupExtension implementation
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I convert if the input value is of type `StatusMessage` and the target type is `typeof(Brush)`, which is the Type of the `Foreground` property. I just chose some colors, you may use different colors or even more complex brushes if you like.

In XAML, the namespace of the converter needs to be referenced. In my case its just `WpfApplication2` associated to the XAML namespace name `c`

```
<Window 
    [... other properties]
    xmlns:c="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2">
```

Now, when binding to the foreground property, utilize the converter

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}" Foreground="{Binding StatusMessage,Converter={c:StatusMessageToColorConverter}}" />
```

This should do the trick.

Now to the other part about dynamically changing the value. Your viewmodel class needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event whenever a value is changed. As an example, see the following class that only contains the two properties of your example and the necessary notification logic.

```
public class ItemModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = null)
    {
        var tmp = PropertyChanged;
        if (tmp != null) tmp(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }

    private string _Status;
    public string Status
    {
        get { return _Status; }
        set { _Status = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    private StatusMessage _StatusMessage;
    public StatusMessage StatusMessage
    {
        get { return _StatusMessage; }
        set { _StatusMessage = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}
```

More complex viewmodels can follow the same approach. For less update overhead, compare the current value and the new value in the setter and only notify if the value actually changes.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer, please see my edit.

Comment: @davidhol You are binding to your typename `StatusMsg` but you need to bind to the propertyname `StatusMessage`.

Comment: OK i changed it and remove DisplayMemberBinding from GridViewColumn (not working with this) and now i cannot see my status message at all

Comment: @davidhol If you see the status message without foreground binding and can't see it with the binding (nothing else changed), you should put a breakpoint in the converter and check what it actually does. **edit** you removed your `Text="{Binding Status}"` from the property bindings...

Comment: My current XAML is in my edit, i can se my status message but the color not changing, and after put breakpoint in StatusMessageToColorConverter inside Convert i can see that the code not executed.

Comment: @davidhol It was already explained to you in another question that `DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status}"` ignores your `CellTemplate`. You need to bind the `Text` property inside the `TextBlock`. It is already in my answer, so I don't have anything to edit.

Answer (score 0):

In your view model you could add a property called GetColour that looks at the current enum value and returns a colour. Then just bind the GetColour property in your xaml.

Comment: Are you familiar with MVVM? Specifically the ViewModel and how it works? INotifyPropertyChanged? 2 Way Bindings?

Comment: You may need to modify your binding to Mode=2 Way

Comment: Can you show me what to change according my edit please ?

Comment: On second thought, when you modify your status. You may need to raise a property changed on the Colour property as well.